# macOS 12: cannot give permissions to an app to access a folder

Tags: macos, security, permission, monterey

I am trying to give permissions to an app I downloaded to access the "Documents" folder in my Mac. I go to System Preferences, Security & Privacy, Privacy, unlock by typing my password... and the "+" button is still greyed out (see screenshot). Why would that be?

This is all on macOS 12.6.3. Yes, my account is an admin. account.

[image]

Comment: Is SIP on or off?

Comment: It's on. I can't believe. Do I have to disable it every time I want to do this? I'm already providing my password to admin the machine!

Comment: No. It needs to be on. You just found one of those things that, though I have no clue as to why, will not work if it's off.

Comment: So it's not because it's enabled? I don't need to disable SIP to give access to the folder?

Comment: No, you do not need to disable SIP in order to give access to a folder. That would defeat the whole purpose of the thing, and be very non-user friendly.

Comment: @PaulJ Is your Mac by chance managed by someone else? (i.e. an employer, an educational institution or similar?)

Comment: Putting out there that on my 12.6.5 machine, I (the only admin)  cannot add items to the list, but I can **remove** items.   Is this one of those "the application has to attempt access in order for the OS to generate the pop-up asking for access" things?

Answer (score 1):

The application has to request access.  From the help text:

> Allow apps to access files and folders in different locations on this
> Mac. The listed apps have requested access.

Comment: The problem is that my app doesn't request access. When it tried to create a file there, it just says "Can't create project in this folder". i'll check whether the developers took the newer Macs into account and whether there is a new version

Comment: Also, and this is more of a UI design thing: if it's the app that has to request access, then it doesn't make much sense to put those "+" "-" buttons there, right? Kinda misleading for the user...

Comment: I couldn't say.  I don't know what an application does that counts as a "request".